# Proof about interval graphs being perfect

Tags: graph-theory, intervals, proof

I know that interval graphs are perfect, because when you use *k* colors to color a graph, the maximum clique size of the said graph is also *k*.

My main question is how to begin this proof.

Do I use induction for this? The base case would be simple, with the one and the only interval receiving the sole color and the maximum clique size being one as well.

What's the best way to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

The standard proof uses a greedy algorithm to color the graph, not induction. You order the intervals by their left endpoint, and start greedily coloring each of them starting from the left. It is quite easy to show that if you have to use the (clique number + 1)'th color at any point, then there is a clique of size (clique number + 1) -- which is obviously not possible. This proves that the clique number is equal to the chromatic number.

And any induced subgraph of an interval graph is also an interval graph, so interval graphs are perfect.